# Space between Divs

Tags: html

In my code a strange space is rendered in between two inner most divs in the following html structure

```
<body>

    <div class='DatePicker'>
        <div id="dayDiv" class='DayDiv' style='background-color:blue'>
            <div class="" style='display: inline-block; height:10%;width:10%;background-color:red;vertical-align:top'>

            </div>
            <div class="" style='display: inline-block; height:10%;width:10%;background-color:red;vertical-align:top'>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The innermost divs are rendered but with space in between of them and I want to remove that.

Following is the [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/hfx3Q/) to see the page with styles-sheet.

Note: Margin, border and padding is 0 for all the elements

Comment: OK; what's your question?

Comment: why don't you create a class for the inner divs?

Comment: @WillChesterfield I want to remove the space

Comment: @blachawk no problem in creating class but what different style property I would add in class that would solve the issue

Comment: @WillChesterfield  display:inline-block plus float:left

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the white space between the divs and it goes away

```
    <div class='DatePicker'>
        <div id="dayDiv" class='DayDiv' style='background-color:blue'>
            <div class="" style='display: inline-block; height:10%;width:10%;background-color:red;vertical-align:top'>

            </div><div class="" style='display: inline-block; height:10%;width:10%;background-color:red;vertical-align:top'>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hfx3Q/3/)** or **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hfx3Q/4/)** (uses HTML comments)

Comment: Thanks dude, really weird, just an indentation problem thats it.

Answer (score 1):

All above answers are correct, you got spaces between divs because there is a space in your markup.

You can fight this behaviour in several ways:

**Remove spaces in markup**

Sticking together the closing `</div>` with the next `<div>`

```
    <div class='DatePicker'>
        <div id="dayDiv" class='DayDiv' style='background-color:blue'>
            <div class="" style='[all your styles]'>
            Your content...</div><div class="" style='[all your styles]'>
            Your content...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Use negative margins**

I don't recommend this way because you really don't know *exactly* how many pixels you need to reduce. The space is one character width. Often, it counts 3px or 4px, but... is unsure.

```
<div class="" style=' /*New style*/ margin-left:-4px; /*End new style*/ display: inline-block; height:10%;width:10%;background-color:red;vertical-align:top;'>
```

**Set width of the font to "0"**

If you are using em instead of px, you could avoid this method. It can give you troubles in child elements, and extra markup.

```
<div class="" style=' /*New style*/ font-size:0; /*End new style*/ display: inline-block; height:10%;width:10%;background-color:red;vertical-align:top;'>
    <div style="font-size:12px;">Your content...</div>
</div>
```

**Float the div**

Instead of use `display:inline-block;` you could use `float:left;`. This method probably requires to you the use of a [clearfix method](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html).

I retrive the info from CSS Tricks. You could get [more info there](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is weird, but in HTML if you have *empty lines* between elements it creates a space there. Remove the empty lines to make the space magically disappear.

```
<div class="" style='display: inline-block; height:10%;width:10%;background-color:red;vertical-align:top'>

</div><div class="" style='display: inline-block; height:10%;width:10%;background-color:red;vertical-align:top'>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a space...

```
<body>
    <div class='DatePicker'>
        <div id="dayDiv" class='DayDiv' style='background-color:blue'>
            <div class="" style='display: inline-block; height:10%;width:10%;background-color:red;vertical-align:top'></div>
            <div class="" style='display: inline-block; height:10%;width:10%;background-color:red;vertical-align:top'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get rid of the space?

Add `float: left` to your divs.